# How does python understand where a module is located in my computer without using system path?

Tags: python, import, module

How does a python script understand  to which module I refer to without file system path?

How can both:

```
import a
```

and:

```
import imp
a = imp.load_source('a',r'C:\Users\dimitris\Desktop\PythonData\main.py')
```

work?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: the first example would not work unless you were in the same directory or it is in your pythonpath

Comment: Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C-Python uses the $PYTHONPATH environment variable which lists search locations for modules.  By ordering this list of directories you indicate the search order.  In addition to that, the local directory from which you called python is also searched.

Other distributions, such as Anaconda and Enthough use other methods of searching for installed packages as well.